# How to use docker inside docker container in a safe way

Tags: docker

I have some docker containers running on my docker environment (on a CentOS  VM) which need docker inside. So I mount `/var/run/docker.sock` inside the containers.

Now I'm creating `/etc/default/docker` in which I put

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://xx.xx.xx.xx:2376"
```

But now my question is: which IP is `xx.xx.xx.xx`? Is it the IP of the host or the IP of a container? + Is this the savest way to let a docker container use the socket? (=use docker in docker)

Comment: It is not fully clear what you actually want to achieve. Do you just want to access the hosts Docker daemon (e.g. creating containers on it) or do you actually want a full blown new docker daemon inside your container?

Answer (score 0):

Working with Docker in Docker can be tricky. I would recommend using the official Docker image with the `dind` tag. You shouldn't need to specify the `DOCKER_HOST` in options as it will be correctly configured. For example running:

`docker run -ti --name docker -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --privileged docker:dind sh`

Will drop you to a shell inside the container. Then if your run `docker ps` you should see a list of containers running on the host machine. Note the `--privileged` flag is required in this case as we are accessing the Docker daemon outside the container.

Hope this helps!

Dylan

### Edit

Drop the `--privileged` flag from the above command due to security issues highlighted by Alexander in the comments. You also can drop the `dind` tag as its not required.

Comment: It should not be required to use the `dind` tag here. It's probably even dangerous because if you forget the `sh` at the end, it would try to start a new daemon inside Docker which might try to overwrite the host volume...not sure if this will even work or if it may have consequences for the host Docker daemon.

Comment: @alexander It appears the documentation on this is out of date - I will update my answer! Thanks! There was a time in the past where the elevated permissions were required for this to work. I agree entirely with you on that flag and it should be used with caution

Comment: If I remember correct, --privileged was always only required for true "Docker in Docker" where you needed a full blown daemon inside Docker. For the simple case where you only want to reuse the daemon from the host (by using the docker.sock mount), this was never required.

Answer (score 0):

Running docker within docker is not so trivial an you might have a good reason for doing that.

The last time I was doing that, I was using `dind` (docker in docker) and had to mount the socket (`/var/run/docker.sock`) and used it in a combination with the `--privileged` flag. However things might have changed now (see https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/15596) and it should be able to run it without the socket mount:

`docker run --privileged -d docker:dind`

So be sure to check out this comprehensive guide at https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/

Comment: --privileged should not be required if you only want to access the hosts Docker daemon. Also, please see my comment on Dylan's answer.

Comment: "I have some docker containers running on my docker ... which need docker inside." lets me conclude that he want's to run docker within docker?